# message.guild.roles.create seems to not work

Tags: discord.js

Though this command should work perfectly I couldn't find an error.

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'AMERICANO',
    color: 'RED',
    permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR'
  }
})
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using v12 since its a new one

Comment: Tho command was working perfectly 5 hours ago

Comment: Try adding `.then(() => console.log("here"))` and `.catch(console.error)`, most likely the bot can't add the administrator perm

Comment: And? How is it 'not working' now? What error?

Comment: There is no error @Karizma

Comment: @underscore_d Tbh it was working since yesterday.

Comment: Before you execute the method try logging something and see if anything logs, might not even be executing

Comment: @Karizma already tried. made command yesterday and was working, nothing was edited

Comment: contain the code in a try-catch statement

Comment: Did It, but no errors

Comment: So your bot is online, and other commands work but not this one, or does all the commands not work? Also, just double check if your bot is online.

Comment: @Pepe_Worm only that command wasn't working, after I changed a bot token it worked again, this was very odd, and it wasn't supposed to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due `DISCORD API`, the issue was fixed after changing bot account, I assume it was due overloading it

Comment: What do you mean by `changing bot account`?